# How to increase the size of a div according to div child?

Tags: html, css

I have two div  :

```
<div class="Content">
          <h1>Hello World !</h1
                 <div class="POST">
                      My Post ......
                  </div>

</div>
```

CSS (Content ) :

```
.Content
{

    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-220px;
    top: 165px;
    width:707px;
}
```

CSS (POST) :

```
.Post
{
    position:absolute;
    top:404px;
    width: 669px;
    left: 23px; 
}
```

i want a css code like that when `<div class="content">` increses, other `<div class="parent">` height increses so

Comment: If you don't set a size to `class="content"` then it will automatically size to fit the children so long as their positions are not set to absolute or fixed

Comment: First of all you have to close your `h1` tag

Comment: You arent showing enough HTML here, where is the parent element? Also, do you have any CSS applied?

Comment: I want a css code.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ...and why so much `position:absolute`? It's a horrible way to do layout.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

html:

```
<div class="Content">
     <h1>Hello World !</h1>
           <div class="POST">
           My Post ......
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
 .POST
    {
        width: 200px;
        height:100%;
        background:red;
    }

.Content
{
    background:blue;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zaHAL/

Please, also learn how to write code...

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

HTML

```
<div class="Content">
          <h1>Hello World !</h1>
                 <div class="Post">
                      My Post ......<br>
                     sdfasfasdadfasfdasfdasdf<br>
                     asfasfa<br>
                        sdfasfasdadfasfdasfdasdf<br>
                     asfasfa<br>
                        sdfasfasdadfasfdasfdasdf<br>
                     asfasfa<br>
                        sdfasfasdadfasfdasfdasdf<br>
                     asfasfa<br>
                  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Content
{
    top: 165px;
    left: 50%;    
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.Post
{
    top:404px;
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    left: 23px; 
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: BR is there just to show that if the height of the child div increase then the height of the parent div will increse as well. He by no means have to use br. I think thats what he is asking for.

Comment: <p> is another option but then you will need a closing tag as well. However, <br> is just one peace of code that shows the trick. Anyways, he did not ask for which tags to use to break lines. He asked for the solution to increase the height of the parent div when child div increases, and that is shown in this solution perfectly.

Comment: yes but `br` is a dirty way to do the trick. Using `<p>` is much 'cleaner'. 
As your solution for his problem is written here perfectly, mine is as well. But doesn't use `br` and neither an `<p>` I know that. But it was the HTML of the poster, and his question had to do with CSS code. Not with HTML, so I left the HTML alone.

Comment: your solution has a fixed  height:100px; on the parent div. This means that if the content in the child div exceeds that amount it will start overflowing.  I don't think poster wants that. no one voted your answer as negative.